# Collapsing a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes.

```
> pairs
$`1`
  Var1         Var2
1 up1          down1
4 up2          down2

$`2`
  Var1         Var2
3 up1          down2
2 up2          down1
```

I want to collapse these to two strings and append them to a vector (or column of a dataframe)

I've declared a dataframe (I want to add another column to this later), specifically using stringsAsFactors = F

```
ratioGroups<-data.frame(ratioGroupName = character(), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(ratioGroups)<-c("groupName")
```

First I've isolated each dataframe

```
group1<-as.data.frame(pairs$`1`)
group2<-as.data.frame(pairs$`2`)
```

Then I'm forcing everything in them to characters rather than factors and putting all that back into a dataframe.

```
group1<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(group1, as.character)))
group2<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(group2, as.character)))
```

I then use collapse to collapse each row to a single word

```
ratioNames1<-apply(group1,1,paste,collapse="_")
ratioNames2<-apply(group2,1,paste,collapse="_")
```

Which works fine.

```
> class(ratioNames1)
[1] "character"
> ratioNames1
                 V1                  V2 
"up1_down1"         "up2_down2" 
>
```

I then convert each of those to a single line

```
ratioGroup1<-paste(ratioNames1[1],ratioNames1[2],sep="-")
ratioGroup2<-paste(ratioNames2[1],ratioNames2[2],sep="-")
```

Which again, works fine. I then attempt to add these to the initial dataframe. The first one works fine though for some reason it overwrites the column name(??)

```
> ratioGroups
[1] groupName
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> ratioGroups<-rbind(ratioGroups,ratioGroup1)
> ratioGroups
  X.up1_down1.up2_down2.
1    up1_down1-up2_down2
>
```

Attempt to add another line and

```
> ratioGroups<-rbind(ratioGroups,ratioGroup2)
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "up1_up2-down2_down1") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
>
```

I'm having one of those afternoons where I can only think of R as being particularly asinine. I force everything to characters rather than levels, everywhere and it still try's and converts something into a factor somewhere. I'm guessing there'll be some default behavior of one of the commands I'm using that'll convert everything into a factor because of reasons. Any idea where I'm going wrong? What I'm after would look something like:

```
> ratioGroups
  groupName
  up1_down1-up2_down2
  up1_down2-up2_down1
```

where I could just keep appending names  with an rbind.

Comment: `sapply(lapply(pairs, apply, 1, paste, collapse = '_'), paste, collapse = '-')`?

Comment: See, that just makes me despair. Don't get me wrong, many thanks for the answer, and it's much better than my wodge of code. I've been using R for a couple of years now, after many, many years of Perl, C++, Python, etc. And it's things like this that make me think that I'm never going to understand the minds of the people who thought this was a sensible way for a language to operate. <sighs>

Comment: You can also use do.call to avoid three apply functions `sapply(lapply(pairs, function(x) do.call("paste", c(x, list(sep="_")))), paste, collapse="-")`

Comment: It's weird because you're transforming your data in three different dimensions. You can unnest the calls if you like the pipe: `library(tidyverse) ; pairs %>% map(unite, var, Var1, Var2) %>% flatten() %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = '-')` or variants thereof. Or just save variables in between.

Comment: Don't get frustrated by the language due to the answers here. We are combining multiple steps into one line. You could do something similar in Perl, but it would be nowhere near as concise with C++ and Python AFAIK. If you saw the same approaches in many steps it would be more readable.

Comment: It's not so much that it's unreadable. In that single line, I find it quite readable. It's just something I would never, ever have even begun to have conceived of doing it that way.

Comment: The new `tidyr` package should be helpful for this.